# Apex heap size too large : Error for fieldset

Tags: apex, api, fieldsets, for

I have to copy field values from Object `Business_Plan_abv__c` to `Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c` where API Names are exactly matching. For that I am using fieldset on `Business_Plan_abv__c` object. But it throws below error.

> Apex heap size too large

**Apex code snippet**

```
 global class batchInsertbp implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    Public String strParameter;
     Public String strParameter1;
    public Set<String> terr = new Set<String>();
    Public Map<String, List<Business_Plan_abv__c>> accMap = new Map<String, List<Business_Plan_abv__c>>(); 
   //     Public Map<Id, String> IdMap = new Map<Id,String>(); 
    public Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c bpdata = new Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c();
    public batchInsertbp(String strParam , String strParam1) {
        strParameter = strParam;
        strParameter1 = strParam1;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // List<Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c> BPApprovalProcessExist = [select Id, Franchise_abv__c, territory_Name__c from Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c where Franchise_abv__c=:strParameter and Quarter_Time_Period__c=:strParameter1 ];

        for(Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c bp : [select Id, Franchise_abv__c, territory_Name__c from Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c where Franchise_abv__c=:strParameter and Quarter_Time_Period__c=:strParameter1 ])
        {             
        terr.add(bp.Territory_Name__c);
        }
       // String query = 'Select Name,Id,Salesforce_abv__c,Franchise_abv__c from Territory where Franchise_abv__c =\''+strParameter+'\' and Name NOT in:'+terr;
        System.debug('strParameter@'+strParameter);
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Name,Id,Salesforce_abv__c,Franchise_abv__c from Territory where Franchise_abv__c =: strParameter and Name NOT in: terr ]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Territory> scope) {
        system.debug('Franchise@@'+strParameter);    
         List<Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c  > BpToInsert = new List<Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c>{};
           List<Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c  > insbpdata = new List<Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c>{};
    List<String> scopenames = new List<String>();
    for (Territory t : scope)
    { system.debug('Territory Name@'+t.Name);
      scopenames.add(t.Name);
    }
    system.debug('scopenames@@'+scopenames);
     List<Business_Plan_abv__c> bp = [select Id,Ambassador_Enrolments_abv__c,Biologic_TRx_Growth_last_3_months_abv__c,Biologic_TRx_Growth_last_6_months_abv__c,Biologic_Index_last_3_months_abv__c,Biologic_Index_last_6_months_abv__c,Business_Planner_Flag_abv__c,Call_Activity_Avg_of_last_3_quarters_abv__c,Call_Priority_Decile_abv__c,City_abv__c,Comments_abv__c,Core_Target_abv__c,Creon_Decile_abv__c,Creon_TRx_growth_change_abv__c,Creon_TRx_Normalized_abv__c,Creon_TRx_Raw_abv__c,DMARD_TRx_Growth_last_3_months_abv__c,DMARD_TRx_Growth_last_6_months_abv__c,DMARD_Index_last_3_months_abv__c,DMARD_Index_last_6_months_abv__c,Dosing_Opportunity_Ranking_abv__c,EPI_Risk_Decile_abv__c,External_Id_abv__c,First_Name_abv__c,Account_abv__c,Growth_opportunity_Decile_abv__c,HCP_Accessibility_Rating_abv__c,HQ_Call_Plan_Flag_abv__c,HQ_Recommended_Frequency_abv__c,Humira_TRx_Growth_last_3_months_abv__c,Humira_TRx_Growth_last_6_months_abv__c,Humira_Decile_abv__c,Humira_Market_Share_last_3_months_abv__c,Humira_Market_Share_last_6_months_abv__c,Humira_Market_Share_Growth_lst_3_mon_abv__c,Humira_Market_Share_Growth_lst_6_mon_abv__c,Humira_TRx_last_3_months_abv__c,Humira_TRx_last_6_months_abv__c,IMS_Number_abv__c,Last_Name_abv__c,Last_Quarter_Calls_By_Rep_abv__c,Last_Quarter_Calls_Rheum_abv__c,Lipase_unit_per_Rx_Strength__c,Market_Decile_BIO_abv__c,Market_Share_abv__c,Market_Share_Growth_abv__c,Market_Share_opportunity_Ranking_abv__c,Market_TRx_Normalized_abv__c,Motivational_Profile_abv__c,My_Action_abv__c,My_Frequency_abv__c,
PDRP_Flag_abv__c,PERT_Decile_abv__c,Priority_1_abv__c,Priority_3_abv__c,Priority_4_abv__c,Priority_5_abv__c,Reason_for_Add_Drop_abv__c,Specialty_abv__c,State_abv__c,Street_Address_abv__c,Suggested_Priority_abv__c,Target_Inclusion_Reason_abv__c,Target_Plan_Flag_abv__c,Territory_abv__c,Total_Planned_calls_to_HCP_abv__c,Zip_abv__c from Business_Plan_abv__c where Territory_abv__c in :scopenames];
     system.debug('terr@@'+terr); 

      for(Business_Plan_abv__c obj : bp) 
     {
     system.debug('BusinessPlan@'+obj);
     if(!accMap.containsKey(obj.Territory_abv__c)){
         accMap.put(obj.Territory_abv__c, new List<Business_Plan_abv__c>{obj});
        system.debug('accmap new@'+accmap.get(obj.Territory_abv__c));
    }else{
         List<Business_Plan_abv__c> tempList = accMap.get(obj.Territory_abv__c);
         tempList.add(obj);
         accMap.put(obj.Territory_abv__c, tempList);
         system.debug('accmap old@'+accmap.get(obj.Territory_abv__c));
    }


     }
     system.debug('scope@@@'+scope);
     system.debug('accmap@@@'+accMap); 
        for(Territory a :scope)
        {
        system.debug('accMap.get(a.Name)@'+accMap.get(a.Name));
        system.debug('check exist@'+accMap.keyset().contains(a.Name));
        If(accMap.get(a.Name) != null) 
         { 
       /* Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c  newbp = new Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c ();

        newbp.Franchise_abv__c =a.Franchise_abv__c;
        newbp.Territory_Name__c=a.Name; 

        newbp.Status_abv__c = 'Saved';
        newbp.Quarter_Time_Period__c= strParameter1 ;
        newbp.External_ID_abv__c = a.Name+'_'+strParameter1 ;

        BpToInsert.add(newbp);*/

        BpToInsert.add(
            new Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c(
                Franchise_abv__c =a.Franchise_abv__c,
                Territory_Name__c=a.Name,
                Status_abv__c = 'Saved',
                Quarter_Time_Period__c= strParameter1,
                External_ID_abv__c = a.Name+'_'+strParameter1        
            )
        );

         }
       }
       system.debug('BpToInsert@Check'+BpToInsert);
        if(!BpToInsert.isEmpty()){
    //system.debug('BpToInsert@Check'+BpToInsert);
    Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(BpToInsert, false);


    for (Integer i = 0; i < srList.size(); i++ ) {
     Database.SaveResult sr = srList[i];
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {

           system.debug('accmap@'+accMap.get(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c)); 
           system.debug('TerrName@'+BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c);
             //Alstitem.External_ID_vod__c = actID+'-'+key;


           if(accMap.get(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c) != null)
         {   for(Business_Plan_abv__c j: accMap.get(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c))
             { 
             Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c bpdata = new Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c();
             bpdata.Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c= sr.getId();  
             bpdata.Territory_abv__c= BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c;
             bpdata.External_Id_abv__c = j.Account_abv__c+'_'+sr.getId();
            Schema.FieldSet fieldSetToCopy = Schema.SObjectType.Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c.FieldSets.Batchinsert;

            for (Schema.FieldSetMember dataField : fieldSetToCopy.getFields()) {
              bpdata.put(dataField.getFieldPath(), j.get(dataField.getFieldPath()));
            } 


             insbpdata.add(bpdata);

             }

         }
             system.debug('insbpdata@@'+insbpdata);

        }
    }
    try {
        INSERT insbpdata;
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
}

        //insert BpToInsert;   
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You could take `Schema.FieldSet fieldSetToCopy = Schema.SObjectType.Business_Plan_abv__c.FieldSets.Approval_Process_Data_Fields;` outside of for loop.

Comment: But will that resolve the issue?

Comment: Same issue happening.

Comment: Is that the code where issue occurring? can you provide the complete code.

Comment: yes it's happening there only. I have updated the full code here.

Comment: I believe this is happening because your Batch is Stateful

Comment: Then what it should be? Can you please tell me the change